# Google Cloud Datastore, Python Client, add_filter returns no results

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have this code which does not print anything:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client()
query = client.query(kind='Kind')
query.add_filter('status', '=', 'new')
results = query.fetch()

for result in results:
        print result
```

When I comment out the line `query.add_filter('status', '=', 'new')` it prints all entities as expected.

My index.yaml file is:

```
indexes:
- kind: Kind
  properties:
  - name: increment
  - name: status
```

Status on Datastore dashboard is "Serving"

I create the Entities with this code from App Engine:

```
class Kind(ndb.Model):
        json = ndb.TextProperty()
        status = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=True)
        increment = ndb.IntegerProperty()
        created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        @ndb.toplevel
        def post(self):
                parajson = self.request.get("json")
                parastatus = self.request.get("status")
                paraincrementtmp = self.request.get("id")
                print paraincrementtmp
                paraincrement = int(paraincrementtmp)
                #print parajson         

                write = Kind(json = parajson,
                        status = parastatus,
                        increment = paraincrement)
                key = write.put()
```

How can I get the add_filter part in the first snippet to work?

Comment: Do you see any related error in [Stackdriver Error Reporting](https://console.cloud.google.com/errors)?

Comment: Could you confirm if [Google Console][4] the `status` property is of type `Text` and if it has an `Index this property`" checkbox?

Comment: In the results displayed for the query without the filter do you have any with status `new`?

Comment: It's possible that you changed indexed=True after you wrote all your entities.  You can check your entities by removing the filter and printing out Kind._properties['status']._indexed  (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/modelclass#intro_properties)

Comment: I started over and it worked, I dont know...thx anyway